# SSH over IPvanish

Tags: ssh, remote, openvpn

Hello I have been trying already for several days to access my tiny server via ssh with openVPN.

Everything works fine without the VPN.

I have tried all that you can find on forums...add an ip rule , iptable etc...
Funny thing is that I can access it over Weaved Proxy with the VPN still running.

Any help I would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my outputs

```
$ sudo ip rule list 
0:  from all lookup local 
32765:  from 192.168.1.81 lookup 128 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default 

$ ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:4d:b0:17  
          inet addr:192.168.1.81  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2015:7c30:68c8:c380/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8064 errors:0 dropped:19 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5993 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:848028 (828.1 KiB)  TX bytes:829898 (810.4 KiB)


tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:172.20.YY.XXX  P-t-P:172.20.YY.XXX  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1833 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3752 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:132931 (129.8 KiB)  TX bytes:232573 (227.1 KiB)

$ss -nl
Netid  State      Recv-Q Send-Q                           Local Address:Port                             Peer Address:Port 

tcp    LISTEN     0      128                                          *:6423                                        *:*     
tcp    LISTEN     0      128                                         :::6423                                       :::* 

$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.20.16.1     128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
81.171.XX.YY    192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
128.0.0.0       172.20.16.1     128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
172.20.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

// , According to bestvpn.com, one of the best VPN comparison sites, IMO, IPVanish doesn't support OpenSSH:

[image: No OpenSSH for you!]

https://www.bestvpn.com/compare/expressvpn-vs-ipvanish/

Neither does it support SSTP, Cisco DTLS, or SmartDNS.